# How to subscribe a document.forms.submit() with Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, submit, document

This is my code:

```
Observable.fromPromise(document.forms["myForm"].submit())
.subscribe(
response => {
debugger;
console.log("subscribe submit");
alert("subscribe submit");
console.log(response);
},
error => {
// go for here
debugger;
console.log("error submit");
alert("error submit");
console.log(error);
},
() => {
debugger;
console.log("complete submit");
alert("complete submit");
}
);
```

I want to gets the response of a submit of a form and I try to use an observable and subscribe it.

But I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined at
>   PromiseObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/observable/PromiseObservable.js.PromiseObservable._subscribe
>   (PromiseObservable.js:62) at
>   PromiseObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe
>   (Observable.js:172) at
>   PromiseObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe
>   (Observable.js:160) at
>   Pas3PagamentCompletatComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/certificat-academic/pas3-pagament-completat/pas3-pagament-completat.component.ts.Pas3PagamentCompletatComponent.submitForm
>   (pas3-pagament-completat.component.ts:129) at SafeSubscriber._error
>   (pas3-pagament-completat.component.ts:312) at
>   SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub
>   (Subscriber.js:239) at
>   SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:198) at
>   Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error
>   (Subscriber.js:129) at
>   Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error
>   (Subscriber.js:103) at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1231)

Anybody can help me?

Thanks,

David

Comment: `document.forms["myForm"].submit()` probably doesn't return a Promise

Comment: And what returns the submit method? Perhaps, can I use Observable.fromEvent?

Comment: submit method - is for submitting the form, which simply  fires click event on submit button. I am not sure that it returns anything... you came with wrong approach as the more details you provide, the less sense this question makes

Answer (score 0):

you have to use your view files and bind a method for each form in each component that has a form according to following:

in `<component-name>.html`

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit($event)">...</form>
```

then in `<component-name>.ts` declare a handler

```
onSubmit(event) {
  console.log(event)
}
```

Comment: But I need to do programmatically on the ts component file on this way document.forms["myForm"].submit(). Any idea?

Comment: could you please provide a plunkr/jsfiddle or any other code example, as I am not sure that you came with right approach and I can't really understand the desirable result which you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!

Finally, I've done this way:

Typescript file:

```
submitForm(request: any) {

    let requestData = JSON.parse(request);

    /* ARA PASSEM ELS PARAMETERS DESDE LA REQUEST */
    document.forms["myForm"].param1.value = requestData.param1;
    document.forms["myForm"].param2.value = requestData.param2;
    document.forms["myForm"].param3.value = requestData.param3;
    // fem submit
    document.forms["myForm"].submit();
  }
```

Html file:

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm" action="url" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="param3" value="">
</form>
```

Thanks a lot!!!

David